# Invalid argument: Unsupported locator strategy: null - with chrome driver 76.0.3809.126

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting following error:

```
invalid argument: Unsupported locator strategy: null
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=76.0.3809.126 
  (d80a294506b4c9d18015e755cee48f953ddc3f2f-refs/branch-heads/3809@{#1024}),
   platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)
```

while running my Test and the same code was working fine with the chromedriver-75.0.3770.8. Is there any capabilities needs to be added for chrome driver 76.0.3809.126?

Upgraded selenium package from 3.7.0 to 3.7.10 but no luck.

Downgraded chrome driver to 775.0.3770.8 and it's working fine.

Tried by adding  `SetCapability(CapabilityType.AcceptSslCertificates, true);` but no luck

`driver.findElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='toggle__nav']/span")).click();`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error while working with chrome driver version 77.0.3865.40.

But this time the error occurs while trying to findElement inside a frame. (after using driver.SwitchTo().Frame([iframe IWebElement]);)

It happens with some frames and does not happen with others.

The only workaround I was able to figure out is to inject javascript to do what needs to be achieved within the frame. for example, to click a button...

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor) driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].contentWindow.document.findElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();", [iframe IWebElement]);
```

It would be great if someone can shed some light on why this error occurs in first place and whats the real fix.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when either javascript's object.prototype gets redefined or if the new window is opened and the window.symbol is redfined. Hence latest chromedriver version has issues locating the element.
Chromedriver is in no mind of fixing this issue soon, hence looks like using the javascript is the only option left.
Please have read of :
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3390